# Clean tuple to string

Tags: python, string, tuples

I have a variable `p` which `print(p) = ('180849', '104735')` and I want it to be `p = 180849 104735`

So, basically get rid off `(` and `'` and `,`

Any help with that please?

Answer (score 3):

You can directly unpack the elements to `print` function. By default `print` function insert space between the values(this can be controlled via `sep` argument)

```
>>> p = ('180849', '104735')
>>> print(*p)
180849 104735
>>> print(*p, sep='-')
180849-104735
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this, it is the easier way!

```
tup = ('this', 'is', 'a', 'tuple')
res = " ".join(tup)
```

I hope you like it.